# Can't find OpenWRT driver for Insignia NS-PU98635 USB-Ethernet Adapter on RPi 1B

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet, openwrt

- I have a Raspberry Pi (1B).
- It's running OpenWRT (Barrier Breaker - 14.07, r42625).
- There's an Insignia USB3.0-Gigabit Ethernet adapter (NS-PU98635) plugged in.
- I can't find the driver for that NS-PU98635 adapter.

Can anybody please help me find the NS-PU98635's driver for OpenWRT on my Raspberry Pi 1B?

Answer (score 1):

Insignia doesn't explicitly support linux. They also don't seem to list the chipset used in the adapter in the downloadable documentation (bummer!).

While it may not work, I wouldn't be surprised if they use the same chipset as startech. So try the drivers [listed on their page](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112) version V1.14.4 for kernel 2.6.25 or newer. Post back how it goes.

Comment: Ok. I DL the file straight from my RPi with wget. I haven't compiled anything in a long time. Is there a specific folder to put this zip file? And is the command something like `make install (filename).c`? Oh, and do I have to install a package to unzip the file?

Comment: Unnzip the file to some temp location, doesn't really matter where. `cd` into the folder that is created after you unzip. run `make` then when it finishes, `sudo make install`. Reboot the machine (this may not be necessary but won't hurt). Plug in the device and see if it is recognized.

Comment: Dang, I can't find a unzip utility anywhere - not even with opkg. Is there a cli utility to unzip files on OpenWRT?

Comment: I can't even mount a usb drive to the RPi and transfer files that way with `mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0 /folder`

Comment: Do you not have root/sudo?

Comment: I have root access.

Comment: omg I can't even unzip in a public dropbox folder and wget it from there. For 2 hours I've tried almost everything to be able to get a simple file onto my OpenWRT RPi. Is it not possible?

Comment: You are probably going to want to find someone to walk you through it locally (or at least through chat). I'm not even sure the driver will work. I suggested it as something that you could try and would only take 15 minutes start to finish. If you are struggling to get the files to the system you are in for an uphill battle trying to get the driver you need. Sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I was complaining about the ability to transfer files (in general, not directed toward you) with OpenWRT. Even if it doesn't work, it's still a really good idea and I appreciate the tip. I'll try to find a chat and post on here about how it turns out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While the chipset is not explicitly listed on Insignia's NS-PU98635 adapter description page, I unzipped their driver package at https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU98635/3510527 and found that the drivers are for the Realtek 8152B/8153. Installing the kmod-usb-net-rtl8152 package https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/kmod-usb-net-rtl8152 for OpenWRT on my RPi4 worked for me.